# Slow query with CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, cross-apply

I have the following SQL code which takes several seconds to execute:

```
SELECT instance.startdate
      ,instance.enddate 
FROM (select mr.id 
      FROM meeting_recurrence AS mr 
      inner JOIN meeting_details md ON md.id = mr.meeting_template_id 
      WHERE host_user_id=17) AS p 
CROSS APPLY GetRecurrenceMeetingInstances(p.id,'2018-11-09 11:00:00','2018-11-09 15:00:00') AS instance  
WHERE 21015 IS NOT NULL 
AND instance.meetingid <> 21015
```

The internal select `(select mr.id FROM meeting_recurrence...)` returns in the above example instantly, with two ids.

Running `GetRecurrenceMeetingInstances()` with those two ids separately, returns empty results instantly.

Why does running the entire statement take so long compared to running them separately?

Execution plan image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/je7nK.jpg

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan?

Comment: Posting the execution plan would be good

Comment: What is `WHERE 21015 IS NOT NULL ` supposed to do? Is `21015` a column name? If so, it is not interpreted as such, it is interpreted as an integer, and as such it can not be `NULL`

Comment: I have the the execution plan as a large XML file in MS Management Studio. How do i post it?

Comment: There is a graphical representation as well

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the execution plan with that i assume is the relevant entry highlighted.

Comment: And if you create index: `create index ix_meeting_recurrence on meeting_recurrence(meeting_template_id)`?

Comment: @Stefan did the index helped?

Comment: Since the select involving the meeting_recurrence table is really fast by itself, I don't see how adding an index to that will help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems CROSS APPLY was calling GetRecurrenceMeetingInstances() a lot more than i thought. I solved the problem by saving the inner select in a local variable first:

```
DECLARE @innerresult table(meetingid int)
INSERT INTO @innerresult(meetingid) (select mr.id FROM meeting_recurrence AS mr inner JOIN meeting_details md ON md.id = mr.meeting_template_id 
    WHERE host_user_id=17)

INSERT INTO @timeslots (startdate,enddate) 
    SELECT instance.startdate,instance.enddate 
    FROM (select meetingid FROM @innerresult) AS p 
    CROSS APPLY GetRecurrenceMeetingInstances(p.meetingid,'2018-11-09 11:00:00','2018-11-09 15:00:00') AS instance
```